# Query to return all results except for the first record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a archive table that has records of transactions per locationID.

A location will have 0, 1 or many rows in this table.

I need a SELECT query that will return rows for any location that has more than 1 row, and to skip the first entry.

e.g.

**Transactions table**

```
transactionId  locationId  amount
1              11          2343
2              11          23434
3              25          342
4              32          234
5              77          234
6              11          38938
7              43          234
8              43          1235
```

So given the above, since the locationID has multiple rows, I will get back all rows except for the first one (lowest transacton_id):

```
2              11          23434
6              11          38938
8              43          1235
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to do this. This assumes there would be no duplicate transactionid's.

```
select transactionid,locationid,amount
from
(select t.*, row_number() over(partition by locationid order by transactionid) as rn
from transactions t) t
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is fine.  You could also write it this way, it might give you a little insight into grouping practices:

```
SELECT Transactions.TransactionID, Transactions.locationID, Transactions.amount
FROM Transactions  INNER JOIN
(SELECT     locationID, MIN(TransactionID) AS MinTransaction,
    COUNT(TransactionID) AS CountTransaction
FROM         Transactions 
GROUP BY locationID) TableSum ON Transactions.locationID = TableSum.locationID
WHERE (Transactions.TransactionID <> TableSum.MinTransaction) AND
     (TableSum.CountTransaction > 1)
```